# CoreFoundation cow_cleanup iOS 16 crash

Tags: ios, swift, ios16

Since iOS 16 update and my iOS application crash reports are going crazy. The stack trace on crashlytics starts at main.swift my application entry point to be specific at the function name UIApplicationMain()

```
//  main.swift

import Foundation
import UIKit

/// NOTE: comment out @UIApplicationMain in AppDelegate
UIApplicationMain(
    CommandLine.argc,
    CommandLine.unsafeArgv,
    NSStringFromClass(TimerApplication.self),
    NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self)
)
```

Then the stack trace goes like this

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x736544697263248c

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1c20 objc_msgSend + 32
1  CoreFoundation                 0x2a3cc cow_cleanup + 168
2  CoreFoundation                 0x6444c -[__NSDictionaryM dealloc] + 148
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x15d8 AutoreleasePoolPage::releaseUntil(objc_object**) + 196
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x4f40 objc_autoreleasePoolPop + 256
5  FrontBoardServices             0x6aec -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 176
6  FrontBoardServices             0x6a00 __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient _queue_updateScene:withSettings:diff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 340
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x3fdc _dispatch_client_callout + 20
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x7a5c _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 264
9  FrontBoardServices             0x10f2c __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 52
10 FrontBoardServices             0x10ac8 -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 220
11 FrontBoardServices             0x132a8 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 28
12 CoreFoundation                 0xd622c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
13 CoreFoundation                 0xe2614 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
14 CoreFoundation                 0x6651c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 244
15 CoreFoundation                 0x7beb8 __CFRunLoopRun + 836
16 CoreFoundation                 0x811e4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
17 GraphicsServices               0x1368 GSEventRunModal + 164
18 UIKitCore                      0x3a2d88 -[UIApplication _run] + 888
19 UIKitCore                      0x3a29ec UIApplicationMain + 340
20 MobileApp               0x13fb578 main + 12 (main.swift:12)
21 ???                            0x1c56a9948 (Missing)
```